# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 unable to see partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

I am attempting to dual boot Ubuntu next to my current Windows 8 installation using the following instructions: http://www.simplehelp.net/2013/07/11/the-complete-guide-how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-8/

In step four of the wizard (the "Installation Type" window) I do not see any of my partitions listed. Then, when I click on the "+" or "Change..." nothing happens.

I'm installing on a Dell Inspiron 7520 which has a 32GB mSSD cache drive. I'm thinking this is what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Can you open gparted and provide a screenshot? Also, did you disabled Fast Boot?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is problem with MBR of your disk. Try to check it with fsck (partition should be unmounted during check) from ubuntu live cd.

```
fsck -y -f /dev/your_disk
```

wiki about MBR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

Comment: `fsck` checks file systems not MBR.

Comment: as i know fsck can fix such error when you put main partition with mbr  to it. anyway try to check mbr with any other tool.